# Manipulating SharePoint data from an external website

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, jquery, authentication, rest

I have a website built on SiteFinity. What I am aiming to do is:

1) Retrieve and display the 'Accounts' lists from SharePoint 2013 Foundation on the website for subscribed members.

2) Create and Update an 'Account' in SharePoint from the SiteFinity website.

What do I need to do to achieve these two?

Answer (score 1):

You can interact with SharePoint content remotely with the Client-Side Object Model (CSOM).  To get started, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx.

EDIT:  You can also use the REST api: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx